# How to plot quiver vectors of same length and plot streamlines in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector, velocity

I have a velocity field from a glacier (horizontal: ui, and vertical: wi). I can plot it with the code below. How can I
(1) make sure that all quiver arrows are of equal length?
(2) transform these data into streamlines with arrows pointing the direction?
Thanks!
(see attachment for files)

```
realxh=load('realxh_data.mat').realxh;
realzh=load('realzh_data.mat').realzh;
ui=load('ui_data.mat').ui;
wi=load('wi_data.mat').wi;
figure(1);
quiver(realxh(:,1:nx-1)/1000, realzh(:,1:nx-1), ui(:,1:nx-1), wi(:,1:nx-1));
title('Temperature distribution (°C)');
xlabel('x [km]');
ylabel('Surface elevation [m]');
axis([-10 330 -10 2600])
```

Please see for files: https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2096516-how-to-plot-quiver-vectors-of-same-length-and-plot-streamlines

[image]

Comment: Read the documentation of  `quiver`. You are setting the length of the arrows already